# laravel update() is not working on some models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to update the database record but Laravel update() function is not working. I have fillable array in the model. but still, it is not working.

**The Property Model:**

```
class Property extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'properties';
    protected $primaryKey = 'proID';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [ 'proID', 'ProStatus', 'ProPurpose', 'ProType', 'SubType', 'basePrice', 'unitPrice', 'Width', 'Length', 'LandArea','PropertyNumber', 'water', 'electricity', 'gas', 'severage', 'fk_Street', 'createdBy', 'delete'];

    public function streets(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Street::class,'fk_Street');
    }
    public function hasInstallments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Installments::class,'proID');
    }
```

**The PropertyController:**

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $property  = Property::find($id);
        $property->delete = true;
        if($property->save()){
            return response()->json(['success'=>true]);
        }
    }
```

the `$property->update()` always returns true but record does not update in database.

Comment: dont post screenshot, post actual code

Comment: use `$property->save()` instead

Comment: @N69S I tried but, it is still not working

Comment: @flakerimi this does not make any sense whether screenshots being shared or the actual code. the main thing is the solution if you can provide. otherwise, it screenshots are also useless

Comment: No sir, this post can be seeing by other people way years later and the screenshot can be deleted or something similar, so no one else can see the actual problem anymore... POST YOUR CODE NOT SCREENSHOTS

Comment: Other reason is that I could copy your code, paste it on my answer and edit it. I will not write whole class.

Answer (score 3):

The method `update()` is for mass update wich require an array of attributes and bypass mutators.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $property = Property::find($id);
    $property->update(['delete' => 1]);
}
```

You might want to use `save()` instead

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $property = Property::find($id);
    $property->delete = 1;
    $property->save();
}
```

Both will update the record, you'll need to implement your method's return logic on top of this code but as for updating the record, I think you get the idea.

Comment: `update()` is working in all other controllers of my application. except this one

Comment: this is also not working. it is still giving true but database record is still not updating

Answer (score 0):

Your property table primary key is "proID"

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $property = Property::where('proID', $id)->first();
    if($property->update(['delete' => 1])) {
        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }
}
```